# How to disable ant to output warning info in iterm2?

Tags: java, ant

I use ant to build and deploy a java web project in iterm2, and now I have a problem. When I compile the project, there are so many full screen warnings that I can not read errors reported by ant. Here is my ant javac task def:

```
<echo message="begin compile..." />  
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}"   
    includeantruntime="false" nowarn="on"   
    source="1.7" target="1.7" deprecation="true" debug="true"   
    encoding="UTF-8" classpathref="project.classpath">  
    <compilerarg line="-Xlint:unchecked" />  
</javac>  
<copy todir="${build.dir}">  
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}">  
        <include name="**/*.xml" />  
        <include name="**/*.properties" />  
        <include name="**/*.sql" />  
    </fileset>  
</copy>  
<echo message="end compile..." />
```

How can I tell ant to not display warnings and only display errors?

Comment: Are you saying your code is so bad, that the number of compile warnings and errors are too much to view? If so, try compiling in a IDE, fix all your errors, then use Ant for official build.

Comment: use -Xlint:-<warntype> to remove a specific warning type, but as Andreas said, it will be better to fix warning in your code than hidding them during build...

Comment: Thinks for your reply, and sorry for my english. It is true that screen is full with number of compile warnings after compiling. And also, i try using eclipse to compile the code, but the project is so old ( more than 10 years ) that my eclipse(4.0+) hit many issues. So I choose to use ant to make it more simple to compile and deploy the project, but the only pain is that there is so much warning info output to screen, and it takes me much time to find errors info from warning info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable many kinds of warnings, replace...

```
<compilerarg line="-Xlint:unchecked" />
```

...with...

```
<compilerarg value="-Xlint:none" />
```

Warnings about unchecked conversions *cannot* be disabled from the command line. Instead, you have to manually add `@SuppressWarnings` annotations every place unchecked conversions are occurring in the Java code.